# Address of struct element poorly copied in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, stm32, microcontroller

I work on microcontrollers, a `stm32L4`. I work on an eclipse environment with C.
To explain things simply I have a simple struct to define some elements needed in my project :

```
     struct adc {
        SPI_HandleTypeDef *spi_hal;
        //Adresse de l'esclave avec qui communiquer
        uint8_t numero_adc;
        SPI_HandleTypeDef test_hal;
        registres_adc config;

    };
```

Once I'm in my main program trying to initialize it, the first element being a pointer is poorly copied
When I check the address copied it's not the same. Here is the code and what I get :

```
    adc1->spi_hal =&hspi1;
```

[Results affectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3OkZ.png)

Now the funny part is, that when I copy the address to a pointer element in my main, not with my struct, I get the right address copied.
I would need some insights on this problem.

The full code here :

```
typedef struct adc adc_def;

     struct adc {
        SPI_HandleTypeDef *spi_hal;
        //Adresse de l'esclave avec qui communiquer
        uint8_t numero_adc;
        SPI_HandleTypeDef test_hal;
        registres_adc config;

    };

//------------------------------------
int main(void) {

SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

adc_def *adc1;
adc1->spi_hal =&hspi1;
}
```

Comment: Right off the bat I can see one of the two pointers in your screenshot is `volatile`, so that might be the source of inconsistencies in your program. Please translate that image into text, as it's best not to use images when possible. In any case, it's impossible to tell what exactly is going on without seeing a [mre], which your question does not seem to include.

Comment: Thanks for the review, I edited the question, I've put the result without declaring as volatile
The screen has been edited

Comment: `adc_def *adc1;` <<-- this is a pointer, pointing to nowhere. `adc1->spi_hal = &hspi1;` <<-- now, you derence it.

Comment: Thanks a lot wildplasser it actually worked now, I added  


`adc1 = malloc(sizeof(adc_def));`

 and now it works

Comment: Just remove the asterisk, `adc_def adc1;` so you get a local instance, no need to heap-allocate. Or put it in the global scope for lifetime reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to people answering in comments, I know where the problem comes from

My pointer  was used uninitialized, I only had to allocate memory for it

```
adc_def *adc1;
adc1 = malloc(sizeof(adc_def));
```

Comment: Be aware that dynamic memory allocation is considered dangerous, especially in embedded systems. I advise to avoid it unless you really know what you're doing and you really need it. If you use it, it's best to limit its usage to initialization only. After your execution enters the master loop (or start some RTOS), don't call *malloc* or *free*.